# using DAO object inside servlet, Is it proper to do so?

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee, dao

I am currently working on a web application. I'm confused if it is normal/usual or good practice to use DAO's inside servlets and get data directly and use it. Since it is a hotel booking system that i'm aimed to develop so currently I have a class named "HotelManagement". Servlet uses this class to get any data and this class in turn uses DAO's. What I need to know is what is the standard way or good practice to go with. It would be great to know if someone shed's some light on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a NOT at all a good idea to call DAO objects directly from servlets for developing enterprise web applications.

**You need to architect your web application with different layers with 3 or more tiers like below:**

**Front End Layer**:  Contains the View elements HTML, JSP pages

**Controller Layer**: Contains the Servlets or Controller classes which convert the form data into entity (domain) objects and call services layer & render/dispatch the data back to Views

**Service Layer** : Processes the core business logic and connects with DAOs, you can even split your service layer into multiple layers (Process services, Business Services, etc...), typically they share the responsibility of business logic

**DAO Layer**: Interacts with database to write/read the data

You can look at here for more on this:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12440_01/rpm/pdf/141/html/operations_guide/rpm-og-architecture.htm